# Udp клиент Python 3

Tags: python, сокет, udp

Во время исполнения данного кода:

```
import socket 
UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
sock.bind(('', UDP_PORT))
while True:
    sock.send(b'Hello World')
```

Появляется ошибка:
OSError: [WinError 10057] Запрос на отправку или получение данных  (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Скажите,пожалуйста,что я делаю не так?

Comment: `no address was supplied` - вы не указали адрес, на который шлете пакеты. Укажите его первым параметров метода bind вместо пустой строки

Comment: А куда по вашему пакет вы отправляете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Набросал минимальный рабочий пример клиента, бегло просмотрев [статью на хабре по сокетам](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149077/):

```
import socket
from time import sleep

UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', UDP_PORT))

while True:
    sock.send(b'Hello, World!')
    sleep(1)
```

Соответственно, сервер будет выглядеть так:

```
import socket

UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
sock.bind(('', UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data)

sock.close()
```

Обновил, чтобы было UDP, теперь без разницы в каком порядке запускать клиент и сервер.

Comment: Статья у вас о TCP сокетах. UDP сокеты это отдельный зверь. В частности, в отличии от tcp, udp не ориентирован на соединения, поток (нет гарантии порядка или что вообще данные будут доставлены). [recvfrom, sendto можно использовать](https://pymotw.com/3/socket/udp.html). Практический пример: [mDNS (Bonjour, Avahi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) — udp в отличии от tcp поддерживает multicast.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно явно указать адрес
например:

```
UDP_HOST = 'localhost'
sock.bind((UDP_HOST, UDP_PORT))
```

желательно в методе `send()` передавать текст как `bytes-like` объект, например:

```
text = input('enter text : ')
sock.send(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704597/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-python) на мой свежий udp клиент, сам сталиквался с проблемами подобного рода, но сейчас все отлично