# Параллельное исполнение двух функций python

Tags: python, многопоточность, сокет, udp, multiprocessing

Я новичок в питоне и при написании маленького udp чата возникло желание параллельно что-то писать в консоль и отправлять это заданной паре (хост,порт) и прослушивать сеть, получая текст сообщений в консоль.
Я новичок и в потоках, кто-то когда-то писал, что нужно делать это с помощью threading или multiprocessing, прошу помочь мне, буду крайне благодарен :)

Ниже привожу свой код, где имею класс и три функции в нем , где две - send_sock() и listen_sock() нужно исполнить параллельно:

```
import socket as s

class socket_udp:
    host = ''
    port = 0
    sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_DGRAM)

def init_socket(self):
    while True:
        print('enter IP : ')
        self.host = str(input())
        if (self.host == '0.0.0.0') or (self.host == 'localhost'):
            break
        else:
            print('host must be localhost or 0.0.0.0')
            continue
    try:
        print('enter PORT : ')
        self.port = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print('Port must be integer with base 10')
        print('enter PORT : ')
        self.port = int(input())

    self.sock.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
    print('now listening port ', self.port, ' on IP ', self.host)

def listen_sock(self):
    while 1:
        try:
            msg, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(256)
            msg = str(msg)[2:len(str(msg)) - 1]
            print(msg, 'from :', addr)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('input was interrupted by user')
            break
def send_sock(self):
  #  while 1:
            print('enter text')
            text = input()
            socket_udp.sock.sendto(text.encode('utf-8'),('0.0.0.0',11719)) #(socket_udp.host, socket_udp.port))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параллельное исполнение двух функций, которые вводом/выводом занимаются:

```
import threading

threading.Thread(target=loop, daemon=True).start()
read_input()
```

Полный пример кода (один поток крутит вертушку, а другой ожидает ввод пользователя):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Run two parallel IO functions."""
import itertools
import threading
import time


def loop():
    for c in itertools.cycle('-/|\\'):
        print(c + '\b', flush=True, end='')
        time.sleep(0.3)


def read_input():
    while True:
        try:
            s = input('Input a string to reverse (q to exit):')
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
            break
        if s == 'q':
            break
        print(s[::-1])


threading.Thread(target=loop, daemon=True).start()
read_input()
```

Comment: @PetukhovLive: добавил полный пример кода.

Comment: Код вертушки не работает

Comment: @PetukhovLive: если я явно не написал обратного  в ответе, считайте что я оттестировал код в моих ответах (даже тривиальный).  Поэтому разница может или в фактическом коде, которые вы выполняете, или в окружении, в котором у вас код выполняется. Вы уже дважды написали что у вас что-то не работает, не указав дополнительных деталей (не очень полезно). Задайте новый вопрос с ровно **5** строчками кода (`import`ы + содержимое loop()  функции). Опишите явно какую версию Питона используете, на какой операционной системе, как код запускаете (в IDLE, в PyCharm, в Windows консоли, как-то ещё).

Comment: @PetukhovLive: так как мы сейчас [уже знаем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705297/23044), что код работает, то чтобы не вводить в заблуждение будущих читателей, вы можете удалить ваши комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено способом, описанным выше. Привожу полный исправленный код с выводом:

```
import socket as s
import threading

class socket_udp:
host = ''
port = 0
sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_DGRAM)

def init_socket(self):
    while True:
        print('enter IP : ')
        self.host = str(input())
        if (self.host == '0.0.0.0') or (self.host == 'localhost'):
            break
        else:
            print('host must be localhost or 0.0.0.0')
            continue
    try:
        print('enter PORT : ')
        self.port = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print('Port must be integer with base 10')
        print('enter PORT : ')
        self.port = int(input())

    self.sock.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
    print('now listening port ', self.port, ' on IP ', self.host)

def listen_sock(self):
    while 1:
        try:
            msg, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(256)
            msg = str(msg)[2:len(str(msg)) - 1]
            print(msg, 'from :', addr)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('input was interrupted by user')
            break
def send_sock(self):
     while 1:
            print('enter text :')
            text = input()
            text = input()
            self.sock.sendto(text.encode('utf-8'),(self.host, self.port))

sck = socket_udp()
sck.init_socket()
threading.Thread(target=sck.listen_sock, daemon=True).start()
sck.send_sock()
```

Вывод:

```
enter IP : 
0.0.0.0
enter PORT : 
11719
now listening port  11719  on IP  0.0.0.0
enter text :
hi
enter text :
hi from : ('127.0.0.1', 11719)
hello world!
enter text :
hello world! from : ('127.0.0.1', 11719)
```