# Анимация надписи «Нажмите любую клавишу...» в консоли

Tags: python, вывод

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Нужно просто сделать текст "Нажмите любую клавишу...". Но я же несчастный эстет, и мне всё нужно идеально. Вот вещи, которые я хотел бы реализовать:

1. Я часто видел в программах, как многоточие циклически меняется `. -> .. -> ... -> . -> и т.д.`
2. Я хотел бы, чтобы после нажатия любой клавиши надпись "Нажмите любую клавишу..." исчезала.

Вот я и делаю вывод, что простым input-ом это не реализовать. Но как тогда?

Comment: @jfs, там вроде нет ответа, как обработать нажатие любой клавиши?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да-да. Я сейчас прошёлся по ссылкам. Анимация многоточия удалась, а вот как закончить эту анимация при нажатии на клавишу не ясно.

Comment: Я, вообще, много вопросов читал на stackoverflow, но на этот вопрос ответа не нашёл. Зарегался - не совсем понимаю, что к чему. Поэтому особо не злитесь на меня)))

Comment: @jfs, нашёл более оптимальное решение обработки нажатия клавиши: http://python.su/forum/topic/5346/

Comment: @Qwertiy: автор уже упомянул `input()` для ожидания ввода (анимацию в этом случае в другой поток можно отправить, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704612/23044)). Aвтор несколько вопросов задал—можно было как "слишком общий" закрыть, но я решил лучше привести ссылки на вопросы-дубликаты, которые на отдельные части уже отвечают¶ Представьте N простых тем. Если каждый вопрос по М вопросов может задавать, то вместо N вопросов получим C(M, N). К примеру, если N=1000, а М=3, тогда вместо 1000 простых вопросов получим C(3, 1000)=166167000.

Comment: @PaveTranquil: что вы имеете в виду? kbhit -- не оптимально (непереносимо), select -- не оптимально (непереносимо)

Comment: @jfs, именно для моей ситуации было бы удобнее использовать kbhit. Показываю код: http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1527466085/d2b85ce1/21901367.png

Comment: @jfs, input внизу нужен, потому что (не совсем дружу с терминологией) в памяти забивается одно нажатие клавиши, что в дальнейшем отразится на исполнении кода.

Comment: @PaveTranquil: если вы Enter не нажмёте, то `input()` так и продолжит висеть. Так как ответы на Stack Overflow не только для автора существуют (~95% трафика из поисковиков), то постарайтесь все детали, которые существенны для вашего случая указывать. К примеру, если вас только Windows интересует, то явно в вопросе это упомяните (добавьте метку [windows])

Comment: @jfs, окей, не шарю ещё немного) Извиняюсь)) Особо не принципиально, любую ли клавишу нажимать пользователю или Enter. Надпись назову "Нажмите Enter для продолжения")))

Comment: если вас Enter устроит, то есть простое переносимое решение: возьмите анимацию из [Cоздание анимации пишущей машинки c обратным процессом в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/725081/23044) и запустите её в фоновом потоке как показано в ответе к [Параллельное исполнение двух функций python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/704597/23044) (ваш случай проще, можете вместо `read_input()`, сразу просто `input()` написать).